# How to enable mouse wheel in virtualbox?

Tags: unity, virtualbox, mouse

I've installed on my host ubuntu 10.04 in virtualbox guest operating system ubuntu 12.04. And mouse wheel doesn't scroll vertically the contents of a window. In host works normally.
VirtualBox mouse indicator in the right bottom corner flashhes when I'm using mouse wheel.

Comment: Have you installed Guest additions?

Comment: Installing the guest additions made the mouse wheel work (Guest OS was Mac OS X 10.8)

Answer (score 31):

I also had this same problem, other distros in VirtualBox accepted mouse wheel scrolling without a problem.

My fix was in the "Machine" menu of the VirtualBox window in which Ubuntu was running, select "Disable Mouse Integration".  Mouse wheel scrolling works after that.

I am using a wired mouse into a PS/2 port on the host.

Comment: Worked for me thanx!

Comment: worked for me with wired usb mouse. thanks for the tip.

Comment: Note that mouse wheel scrolling *should* work with mouse integration.

Comment: This has since moved to the `Input` menu instead of `Machine`

Answer (score 12):

You should update to the latest VirtualBox and extension pack, and reinstall vbox addition. Everething works fine after it, tested minute ago.

Comment: This. That way, you don't have to disable mouse integration, which I find very handy.

Comment: This is the actual answer, since you don’t lose any functionality when you do this.

Comment: As long as the latest extension pack is fully compatible, yes. Otherwise disabling mouse integration is the only thing that works. Some oddity is preventing that at the moment.

Comment: I updated VBox a couple of days ago and installed the extension pack and I have this problem. The "disable mouse integration" works. (VBox with ubuntu 12.04 running on mac 10.6)

Answer (score 6):

In my case, (Lubuntu 13.04), while the Disable Mouse Integration hint works, I installed 
virtualbox-guest-x11.  This enabled me to use the mouse wheel