# Mouse scroll not working on Oracle VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, mouse, mouse-scroll, oracle

I have Windows7x64 and Oracle VirtualBox 4.1.18 installed on it.I installed Ubuntu 12.04x64 and when I use it, mouse scrolling(Logitech M175) is not working. What I should do to make it work?

Comment: Did you install [guest additions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox/22745#22745)?

Comment: may you have to install your mouse driver

Comment: Thank you, the problem was with guest additions I installed them via windows and they didn't work proper. After it I reinstalled them at Ubuntu and everything is working.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://askubuntu.com/questions/152742/how-to-enable-mouse-wheel-in-virtualbox, which has better answers than disabling integration

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was with [guest additions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22743/how-do-i-install-guest-additions-in-virtualbox/22745#22745) I installed them via windows and they didn't work proper. After it I reinstalled them at Ubuntu and everything is working.

Answer (score 13):

Disabling mouse integration in virtualbox solved this problem for me.

Comment: Solved the same problem on Debian7 for me.

Comment: Could you please provide how to disable mouse integration... An answer that forces you to do additional search is not ideal

Comment: Holy crap, it worked! +1!

Answer (score 3):

I've found this happened because VirtualBox thought I was holding the Alt key. Focusing the guest OS and tapping Alt a few times seems to restore proper scrolling.

See https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/6171

> I can now reproduce this at will with the following sequence of
>   operations:
>
> 1. Switch out of VirtualBox to another program
> 2. Hold down Alt key
> 3. Click of VirtualBox window
> 4. Observe that the scroll wheel has stopped working

Comment: And don't forget there is also an Alt key on the right side of the keyboard. Both of mine were "stuck"

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this question's answers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152742/how-to-enable-mouse-wheel-in-virtualbox):

> You should update to the latest VirtualBox and extension pack, and reinstall vbox addition. Everything works fine after it, tested minute ago.

This is the correct way to fix this problem without losing functionality, although sometimes, disabling mouse integration is the only way to go.

Comment: I find my own answer useful months later. I'm just surprised this keeps breaking (mouse scrolling), forcing me to update VirtualBox + Extension Pack + Guest Additions.