# Virtualbox not seeing any usb devices in the usb filters settings

Tags: virtualbox, webcam

I was following this question but found a problem.
[Use my webcam with Ubuntu running in VirtualBox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4875/use-my-webcam-with-ubuntu-running-in-virtualbox)

I used guvcview to test the camera, it works. I installed the 12.04 virtualbox release from their website and installed the extension pack. But when I click the usb with the green plus sign it says no devices available.

[image]

Comment: You sure that the extension pack was correctly installed? Did you reboot both machines?

Comment: might be you didn't add your user to the vboxuser group?

Comment: as of virtualbox 5 on 14.04, the user is 'vboxusers' (with an s)

Answer (score 110, accepted):

#### This may help you access the USB devices in your guest OS hosted in Ubuntu

First install ***dkms*** to your host Ubuntu:

- `sudo apt-get install dkms`

Next install ***Gnome-System-Tools*** to your host Ubuntu:

- `sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools`

Now launch the application - **Users and Groups** in host Ubuntu. If you're using Gnome you can do this by tapping the Super key and type user then click *Users and Groups icon* to start up the User Settings.

Click *Manage Groups*, find *vboxusers*, click properties, add your own *user name* and any other desired users to the *vboxusers group*. Click Ok. Alternative to using this GUI tool to add user to the group is to use the command `sudo usermod -a -G vboxusers $USER` .

It will also prove useful to ensure *guest additions* (enables features like mouse pointer integration, [shared folders](https://askubuntu.com/a/890740/212123), shared clipboard, etc.) and *extension pack* (adds features like USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 Host Controller, Host Webcam, etc.) are installed. On command line, in host Ubuntu, use:

`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso` and

`sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ext-pack` .

To install guest additions in guest Ubuntu, click on **"Devices" > "Insert Guest Additions CD Image..."** . Then start a file browser e.g. Nautilus (in Ubuntu), Thunar (in Xubuntu). Here, in the side pane, you will see a new CD image been mounted. Click to go into the folder. Now right click and select to open a terminal in this directory. Then you should run the `VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` script with sudo privilege, as: `sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` . This will install the guest additions. Alternatively, you can select to ***Run*** the script, as allowed by a dialogue box as soon as the guest additions ISO is mounted.

Next you'll have to log out and back in. Now start VirtualBox and proceed with adding the USB devices.

Start the VirtualBox Manager. Select one of the virtual machine of choice from the side panel. Then select from menubar: *Machine -> Settings (Ctrl+S)*. Then in the dialog box select *USB*, then check on *Enable USB Controller*. Then based on whether your Webcam is a USB 2 or USB 3 device, select *USB 2.0* or *USB 3.0* radio button. Next, go to the *Add USB device filters* and add and checkmark the Webcam filter for your device.

[image: addition of device filter]

[image: select USB 3.0 controller]

Now you can start the virtual machine and use your webcam in there.

Comment: ajThapa Thanks! It was just that I wasnt in the users group.

Comment: well scroll still doesnt work

Comment: Please visit this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/152742/how-to-enable-mouse-wheel-in-virtualbox

Comment: `gnome-system-tools` ended up being the last piece I needed.  I'm on Ubuntu GNOME and had already made sure my user was in the `vboxusers` group, the latest extension pack was installed, and that USB was enabled for the VM.  AFter a final reboot USB devices showed up.

Comment: I am on xUbuntu 14.04. I did only "Manage Groups, find vboxusers, click properties, add your own user name" + restart (no need apt-get install). It help. Now VirtualBox see all usb devices. Thanks.

Comment: thanks bro. As @SergXIIIth said, I confirm VirtualBox recognized all my USB devices however some of them like Headset is working and some of them like integrated webcam and my other USB webcam still not working. I disabled either but still the other enabled one is not working :( any idea?

Comment: @Hesam try to change USB modes. Play with USB2, USB3 modes. I remember I had an issue with Web camera and solve it this way.

Comment: `vboxusers does not exist`

Comment: just saved my day... Happy New Year! ❤️

Answer (score 59):

This command will add your account to the vbox users group. It will allow your VirtualBox to detect USB flash drives.

```
sudo usermod -G vboxusers -a $USER
```

`$USER` value is your username. You can see it with `echo $USER`

```
$ whoami
foo
$ echo $USER
foo
```

You could also replace `$USER` by your Home username.

Then logout or reboot your computer and VirtualBox will now detect USB devices.

Sources :
[Virtualbox Documentation on Ubuntu](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/virtualbox#les_ports_usb_ne_fonctionnent_pas) (French)
[VirtualBox/USB - Community Help Wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/USB) (English)

Comment: `usermod -G ...` is error prone, use `adduser $USER vboxusers` instead.

Comment: this is the easiest way.

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer instead. The easiest

Comment: what is vboxusers here? `adduser: The group 'vboxusers' does not exist.`

Comment: @Abhishek Bhatia then try 'adduser $USER vboxuser' If it doesn't work, you can try to install/reinstall virtualbox and the extension pack. Please note, that these commands must be used on the host system and not on the guest!

Comment: This did it for me. Can't believe it was just permissions.

Answer (score 6):

It should be enough to run

```
sudo gedit /etc/group
```

then find `vboxusers` line and add to it's end Your user name.

After this reboot is suggested, but logging out or `kill -9 -1` (which will probably log You out too) and logging in should be enough.

Answer (score 4):

After having added yourself to the `vboxusers` group:

```
sudo gpasswd -a $USER vboxusers
```

If you naturally *do not want* to log out or restart for whatever reasons there are, you may run VirtualBox with a forced effective group:

```
sg vboxusers virtualbox
```

This should be unnecessarily after the next reboot.

Comment: You sir are a magician, previously what I'd end up doing was `su $USER` to start a new shell inside my current one with the new effective group in place. One thing to note is if you want to add any additional arguments to the command you should quote the command after `sg vboxusers 'vagrant up'` in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with Linux Mint 17 (Ubuntu 14.04) using the standard distro version 4.3.20.  gnome-system-tools and dkms were already installed but open-vm-dkms wasn't.  I did this:

```
sudo apt-get install open-vm-dkms
```

After a re-boot, I could see the USB devices. The package exists in Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04 as well so I assume it would work there too.

Could be a dependancy problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Once in VirtualBox, click on Devices --> USB Devices --> click on your desired USB device.  Do you see the desired device?

[image]

Comment: no. Same thing. Just learned that scroll on mouse doesnt work in it  too.

Answer (score 0):

I have Ubuntu 14.04 Lts.Installed 5.0.8 version of oracle Vm and ext. pack.Tried all above solutions.I could't see my usb devices.I downgraded Oracle VM virtualbox  and extention pack to 4.3.32 and worked.
I am outdated but at least works.

Answer (score 0):

My fix was simple...

I had this problem today, and I think it was because I ignored a installation warning about some virtualbox service running. I had to restart my host, but afterward the USB was broken, which brought me here.

I re-installed Virtualbox from scratch, completely removing using "Programs and Features", then installed again.

Now the USB works correctly, I have devices showing up. I had to unplug and replug one of my devices to get it to work within the client however.

Comment: "Programs and Features" is a Windows thing.