# Virtualbox guest Ubuntu OS doesn't recognize USB

Tags: 14.04, usb, virtualbox

I'm trying to pull a file from my USB drive from the guest OS (ubuntu 14.04) in virtualbox (5.0.10). I tried following this question's best response:

[Virtualbox not seeing any usb devices in the usb filters settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365850/virtualbox-not-seeing-any-usb-devices-in-the-usb-filters-settings?newreg=a7284ecb7ed948d9a4a544c6ab0e1f04)

but I don't see "vboxusers" under manage groups.

In virtualbox under settings -> USB  I see the USB filter for my device but it doesn't carry over to the guest ubuntu OS. I also installed the latest virtualbox extension pack which did not solve the problem.

I just want to pull a file from the USB to ubuntu. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the **VirtualBox 5.0.12 Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack** ?

If not, you can download it here:
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads
This should give you support for USB 2.0 and USB 3.0 devices, VirtualBox RDP and PXE boot for Intel cards.

Gael.

Comment: I did this and it still doesn't show up