# Guest not seeing USB devices

Tags: 14.04, usb, virtualbox

Have the same issue as [Virtualbox not seeing any usb devices in the usb filters settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365850/virtualbox-not-seeing-any-usb-devices-in-the-usb-filters-settings) and [Virtualbox not seeing any usb devices in the usb filters settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/365850/virtualbox-not-seeing-any-usb-devices-in-the-usb-filters-settings)

However the group `vboxusers` in the guest OS does not exist. I'm using VirtualBox 5.0.14 with guest additions and Extension pack installed. *Have they changed the group name?*

The groups that do exist in the guest OS are the following:

```
karl adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare vboxsf
```

Also, I can't seem to add a `Add Filter From Device` as no devices are shown in the host OS:

[image]

Comment: On Ubuntu we need to be a `vboxuser` in the **host** to be allowed to grab an USB for use in Virtual Box, for a Windows host this is done with a kernel module that should be loaded.