# This location could not be displayed. You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of"Shared_Folder"

Tags: permissions, virtualbox, windows-7, automount, file-sharing

I am using Virtual Box 5.1 on top of Windows 7 Host OS with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Guest OS. I have already installed VBOXADDITIONS_5.1.14_112924 and restarted the Guest machine. The folder appears as mounted underneath the Devices in Files, and it appears as shared on the Host machine.

What permissions do I need to change on my Host/Guest OS to make this shared folder work?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

You have to add yourself to the shared folders group in the Ubuntu guest.

`sudo adduser $USER vboxsf`

Guest OS needs to be restarted after this.

Comment: Worked for me but required a reboot to the guest VM first.

Comment: It worked for me after logout and login again only.

Comment: Note: No need to replace $USER with anything, the string needs to be input exactly.

Comment: Worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04. Thanks a fortune!

Comment: still relevant in 2022

Comment: `sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf $USER` on centos or other linux that might have different adduser

Answer (score 0):

If you get

```
'Username' is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported
```

then use

```
su root
```

then you can proceed with as suggested by Bora.

```
sudo adduser $USER vboxsf
```