# This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules. Please install the gcc make perl packages from your distribution

Tags: kernel, virtualbox

I am trying to Insert Guest Additions CD Image and then run
VBoxLinuxAdditions.run

I am new to Ubuntu and trying to learn. I am running Ubuntu 18.04LTS through Oracle VM v6.04r. My host laptop is running Windows 10 Pro.
So I went to Devices>Insert Guest Additions CD Image. That created Vbox_GAs_6.0.4 on my Ubuntu Desktop. Then I tried to run VBoxLinuxAdditions.run through the terminal and go the following messages.

```
arijitpc@arijitpc-VirtualBox:/media/arijitpc/VBox_GAs_6.0.4$ sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
[sudo] password for arijitpc:
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing VirtualBox 6.0.4 Guest Additions for Linux........
VirtualBox Guest Additions installer
Removing installed version 6.0.4 of VirtualBox Guest Additions...
Copying additional installer modules ...
Installing additional modules ...
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel
modules.  This may take a while.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: To build modules for other installed kernels, run
VirtualBox Guest Additions:   /sbin/rcvboxadd quicksetup <version>
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the modules for kernel 4.18.0-18-generic.

This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the gcc make perl packages from your distribution.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Running kernel modules will not be replaced until
the system is restarted
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Starting.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the modules for kernel 4.18.0-18-generic.

**This system is currently not set up to build kernel modules.
Please install the gcc make perl packages from your distribution.**
```

Request you to please help me as to what should be done. There are so many information out there, most of which are not working, its confusing.
Also request to please provide me the commands I need to run on the terminal as I am mostly not familiar with most lingo in Ubuntu/ Linux environment.

Answer (score 56):

You probably need to install these 2 packets: virtualbox-guest-utils and virtualbox-guest-dkms

It will require few seconds through this terminal command:

```bsh
sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

Then execute again `sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run` as you did and it should work fine ;)

Comment: The second step (`sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`) isn't possible or necessary.  After the apt install, the additions are installed and working (thanks!)  At least, screen resizing and sharing clipboard with host both work.

Comment: Just restart after installing `virtualbox-guest-utils` and `virtualbox-guest-dkms`.

Comment: `drag and drop` need `sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run`.

Comment: For shared folders you also need to add your user to the group vboxsf: `sudo adduser $USER vboxsf` [see here](https://askubuntu.com/a/890740/503378)

Comment: On Lubuntu 22.04.3 LTS instead of sudo apt install virtualbox-guest-dkms launch: sudo apt install dkms.