# Change/remove "Virtual Box" label of the integrated camera (while using host webcam in virtualbox)

Tags: virtualbox, webcam, input-devices

I am using VirtualBox to run Ubuntu 20.04 and I am using the host webcam in it. However, I need to change the label/name of the webcam which by default has "VirtualBox" as a prefix on it.

Can anyone suggest how can I change the label/name of the webcam?

Answer (score 1):

Go to VirtualBox settings of the VM and click on USB. There enable USB Controller then select USB 3.0 and add USB filter for your webcam as below.

[image]

There is a possibility that your webcam may not show there(I personally verified this issue on many other Linux distributions), then follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/375437/699463) tutorial and then try adding the USB filter for the webcam as mentioned above.

Now start your virtual machine and you can check the changes using `lsusb` , there it will show the webcam properties exactly as you have on your host machine and no more "VirtualBox" prefix in the webcam label :D